# How to message or invite a group without joining it?

Tags: 8, group

I'm using the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module. I created a group(Job Post) with linked content types (Job details).

Scenario:
As a user, I created several jobs.

1. I want to be able to invite/message another group (Business) for them to be aware of my posting without joining this group.
2. Also, because I have more than one active jobs, I want to select a job to send the invite about.
3. Lastly, if I have already did an invitation to that group, I can no longer send twice.

Question: How can I achieve these three items above?

**Note**: a User is someone who creates or posts a job (example: electric power shortage). Businesses are created groups, like electricians. The user should invite this business to get notified about his job.

Comment: I'm using the group module. D8. User is someone who create or post a job(example: electric power shortage); Businesses are created groups like electricians. The user should invite this business to get notified about his job.

Comment: Please review my edit of your question, trying to integrate your comment in it. Feel free to further refine/edit as you want, or just perform a rollback to the prior version if you don't like my edit at all. BTW, "group" module, for D8, is a good choice I think. Too bad it's still waiting for the "Rules" module for D8. If your question was about D7, Group + Rules (+ Message also?) would be the solution for what you're trying to do.

Comment: I thought Rules can be integrated with group module in Drupal 8 as it has already an alpha version.

Comment: "***I thought ...***", really? Have you tried anything already with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module in D8 (not only in combination with the Group module)? If so did it work? Rules (for D7) is amazing, and I trust some day it will also be like that for D8. But there are good reasons why the D8 release of Rules today is "alfa" (one never realizes what has been done, only what remains to be done ...).

Answer (score 0):

As answered in [Get notification message in groups](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/223167/get-notification-message-in-groups?answertab=votes#tab-top), you use [Message Subscribe](https://www.drupal.org/project/message_subscribe) based on your criteria.

You expose the [Message Notify](https://www.drupal.org/project/message_notify) for users, but only difference is here you use a custom module to conditionally display that notification form. If the user has already issued a notification, don't display the form. You should be able to search back through the message log to check if the user has previously notified about this message. Be careful you are not clearing out your message log too often in this case.

If you need to clear out your message log, then you may need to use [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module to flag that the user has already notified about this job post. i.e. - mark the message / job post as flagged whenever a notification has been sent. Only display the Message Notify form for non flagged entities.